# Using subclasses in a superclass, at runtime, without circular import ES6

Tags: inheritance, ecmascript-6, reference, runtime

I'm using ES6, and Browserify if it matters

I have a class named `Entity`

I have a subclass named `Explosion`. In other words, `Explosion` extends `Entity`.

I have a method on `Entity` named `explode`, in which I would like to instantiate an `Explosion`.

I don't wish to `import Explosion` in `Entity.js` because this would create a circular dependency.

I don't actually need `Explosion` to be available right away at compile time. I won't need it until much later on in runtime.

What's the correct and clean way to make `Explosion` available to reference at runtime in methods on `Entity`, without importing it?

**What I have tried**

I read [this article](https://railsware.com/blog/how-to-analyze-circular-dependencies-in-es6) which makes sense. I've done the same with ES5 in a more roundabout way.

I did try `export default () => class Explosion`, which does work, and does make `Explosion` available as a class,

However checking if `Explosion instanceof Entity` will return false.

This isn't desirable as I have assertions in place to avoid any mistakes, which will throw on this check.